# How can I combine two or three reports in SQL from different months?

Tags: sql, asp.net, stored-procedures

I have an ASPX C# application that must generate a report as follow: Previous Month, Current Month, and Next Month. The only one that should be displayed alone in case of choice is Current Month, but Previous Month should be combined always with Current Month and Next Month should be combined with Previous Month and Current Month. (Hope it makes sense).

The report will be printed to a PDF, thus, as mentioned, the only one that must be alone is Current Month if chosen.

There is a dropdownlist that contains the three months which is populated by this SQL code:

```
SELECT  MONTH(DATEADD(month, -month, GETDATE())) AS MonthNumber,
LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,  DATEADD(month, -month, GETDATE())), 9) AS MonthName
FROM (VALUES (1), (0), (-1)) t (month) order by MonthNumber
```

Then, the dropdownlist gets both the numerical value and the month name. When the user clicks March (previous month), it should print a file with March and April. If clicks April, only that month, and if clicks May, then March, April, and May.

The problem I find is how to filter from the dropdownlist the option selected but adding or removing the respective month. Any better idea, suggestions, or corrections would be appreciated.

This is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestingWorksheet]

@MONTHSAGO int,  -- Current = 0 ; Previous = -1

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF(@MONTHSAGO = '')
    begin
        Print 'A month needs to be selected.';
    end
    ELSE

    set @MONTHSAGO = @MONTHSAGO - month(getdate()) ;

    IF (@MonthsAgo is not null)
        begin
            select HNumber, 
            dbo.InitCap(StreetIntersection) as StreetIntersection, 
                        MonthFD, 
                        '' TestDate, 
                        '' StaticPressure, 
                        '' ResidualPressure, 
                        '' FlowRestriction, 
                        '' FlushTime,
                        '' FlushRate, 
                        '' RepairNeeded, 
                        Manufacturer, 
                        '' Note
                from HMaster 
                where  testflag = 1 
                    and hsize >= 4 
                    and monthfdno = month(DATEADD(mm, @MonthsAgo, getdate()))
                order by  monthfdno
```

Comment: You should include Year in you report script, so you avoid get records from other years with the same month

Comment: Question is very unclear.  "The problem I find is how to filter from the dropdownlist the option selected but adding or removing the respective month."  So you have a drop down, you are calling a stored procedure with a parameter for the selection.  Looks like you are checking your int parameter against empty varchar, which is weird.  What's not working?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I was able to figure it out after few hours of analysis. Below I put my own solution.

Answer (score 0):

After few hours of analysis, I was able to find it out by doing this in SQL:

```
if(@MonthsAgo = month(DATEADD(mm,-1, getdate())))
        begin

            select HNumber,  
                        ...
                from HMaster 
                where  testflag = 1 
                    and hsize >= 4 

                order by  monthfdno, HNumber
                end

else if(@MonthsAgo = month(getdate()))
                begin
                select HNumber, 
                ...
                from HMaster  
                where  testflag = 1 
                    and hsize >= 4 
                order by  monthfdno, HNumber
                end
else if(@MonthsAgo = month(DATEADD(mm,+1, getdate())))
                begin
                select HNumber, 
                ...

                from HMaster 
                where  testflag = 1 
                    and hsize >= 4 
                order by  monthfdno, HNumber
                end
```

So, it is passing the values: 3, 4, 5 from the dropdownlist to parameter @MonthsAgo then comparing it with SQL function `month(getdate()).`